# In Ansible, how do I add a line to the end of a file?

Tags: ansible

I would expect this to be pretty simple. I'm using the `lineinfile` module like so:

```
- name: Update bashrc for PythonBrew for foo user
  lineinfile:
    dest=/home/foo/.bashrc
    backup=yes
    line="[[ -s ${pythonbrew.bashrc_path} ]] && source ${pythonbrew.bashrc_path}"
    owner=foo
    regexp='^'
    state=present
    insertafter=EOF
    create=True
```

The problem I'm having is that it's replacing the last line in the file (which is `fi`) with my new line rather than appending the line. This produces a syntax error.

Do I have the parameters correct? I've tried setting regexp to both `'^'` and `''` (blank). Is there another way to go about this?

I'm using Ansible 1.3.3.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Apparently ansible has matured and now (version >2.4.0) according to the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/lineinfile_module.html), The defaults when only the line is specified will append a given line to the destination file:

```
    - name: Update bashrc for PythonBrew for foo user
      lineinfile:
        dest: /home/foo/.bashrc
        line: "[[ -s ${pythonbrew.bashrc_path} ]] && source {pythonbrew.bashrc_path}"
        owner: foo
```

Comment: I verified that it only add only once for one line, but for multiple lines like "abc\ndef\n" it will keep adding.

Answer (score 41):

[The Ansible discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Ansible-project/PSaxOczBo7I) helped get me sorted out on this. The problem is the `regexp` parameter.

Since I only want the line appended to the file once, I need the regexp to match the line as closely as possible. This is complicated in my case by the fact that my line includes variables. But, assuming the line started `[[ -s $HOME/.pythonbrew`, I found the following to be sufficient:

```
- name: Update bashrc for PythonBrew for foo user
  lineinfile:
    dest: /home/foo/.bashrc
    line: "[[ -s ${pythonbrew.bashrc_path} ]] && source ${pythonbrew.bashrc_path}"
    regexp: "^\[\[ -s \\$HOME/\.pythonbrew"
    owner: foo
    state: present
    insertafter: EOF
    create: True
```

Comment: This was the original accepted answer. Switched it @shlomoa's answer for new versions of Ansible (which is why it has less votes at moment.)