# How to append the file using Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

**I'm trying to append a file to the existing file.** When I hit a specific url I get the updated data everytime. **my requirement is to append the updated to the same file** instead of creating a new file everytime. I'm using get_url module to get the file. but the file is not being updated. If I give the destination as new file then data is being copied to new file.

Comment: It can be helpful to post your playbook (or snippets) when asking question.  It can make it easier to provide a better and more detailed answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Ansible, how do I add a line to the end of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19688885/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_url doesn't appear to support that operation.  You may need to retrieve the file and use the [Assemble module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/assemble_module.html) to concatenate (or combine) the files.