# How to save multiple stdout_lines from multple hosts to one txt file using ANSIBLE?

Tags: ansible

The issue that I am having is that the output.txt file keeps getting overwritten when I have multiple hosts. Is there something that I am missing so that I can have information from multiple hosts saved in the same .txt file? This is the playbook that I am currently running.

```
hosts: ROUTERS
gather_facts: false
connection: network_cli


tasks:
  -name: Cellular_hardware
   ios_command:
     commands:
        -  sh run | i hostname
        -  sh cellular 0/2/0 hardware | i Modem Firmware|PRI

  register: output

- name: copy output to file
  debug:
   var: output

- name: copy output to file
  copy:
   content: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}('\n')"
   dest: "output.txt"
```

Comment: Is this already answered in [In Ansible, how do I add a line to the end of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688885/in-ansible-how-do-i-add-a-line-to-the-end-of-a-file) ?

Answer (score 3):

To create one file at the controller with the [output from all hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#caching-facts) use [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html#template-template-a-file-out-to-a-remote-server) and [delegate](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) the task to localhost. Run it [once](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once). For example

```yaml
- name: copy output to file
  template:
    src: output.txt.j2
    dest: output.txt
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
```

```yaml
shell> cat output.txt.j2
{% for host in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
{{ host }}
{{ hostvars[host]['output']['stdout_lines'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

[Fit the template](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) to your needs.

---

The [strategies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#strategies) can influence the availability of the variables. See [ansible_play_hosts_all](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) vs. [ansible_play_batch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html). It is a good idea to split the playbook to 2 plays. Collect the output of all hosts in the first play and write the file in the second play. For example

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- name: Collect output
  hosts: ROUTERS
  gather_facts: false
  connection: network_cli
  tasks:
    - name: Cellular_hardware
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - sh run | i hostname
          - sh cellular 0/2/0 hardware | i Modem Firmware|PRI
      register: output
    - name: Debug output
      debug:
        var: output

- name: Write output to file
  hosts: ROUTERS
  gather_facts: false
  connection: network_cli
  tasks:
    - name: copy output to file
      template:
        src: output.txt.j2
        dest: output.txt
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I you can use lineinfile module and append a record to the file, I have used lineinfile, it worked for me to get output in the file based on audit records.

`- name: Add a line to a file.
   lineinfile:
     path: /tmp/output.txt
     line: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
     create: yes
   delegate_to: localhost`

Comment: There is a problem with the "race". All hosts (forks) will write to the same file. This is not reliable when there are more hosts. See [Ansible lininfile behavior](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ansible-project/3DvVtiynMRU/6w3ht_xHAQAJ).

Comment: You are right about linfinfile if you use strategy: free, but if the job in going in sequential, the fork problem can be avoided.

Comment: Take a look at the results properly. If you have code and results that prove me wrong I'll be more than happy to see it. What is "sequential"? You compare it to strategy "free". There is no such strategy as "sequential". What are you talking about?

Comment: Read [Controlling playbook execution: strategies and more](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#controlling-playbook-execution-strategies-and-more) to learn what strategies are available and what forks are. The "fork" is not a problem. Paralel management of remote hosts is essential. Nobody wants to avoid forks in this use-case.

Comment: Actually, I am using lineinfile module to get output from variable and storing in file, I am using default strategy, I am able to write the output to file to control host